# How to remove bathtub drain flange with nubs?

Tags: drain, bathtub

I have a non-standard bathtub drain flange that I'd like to replace (and also clean up the rust) that has a pair of interior nubs.  The drain is 1.75 inches in diameter, and the nubs sit about 0.5 inches down from the top of the flange.

[image: Drain flange]

I saw two previous questions ([one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/92314/how-can-i-remove-this-bathtub-drain) and [two](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15114/how-to-remove-a-tub-drain-with-no-spokes)) that describe removing a flange with no crossbars/spokes, but can I take advantage of these nubs and use common tools to remove the flange?  I'm concerned that the nubs will even disallow the use of an expanding plug.

EDIT:  Also, it would be very difficult to remove the drain with channel locks due to how it's seated in the tub.

Comment: I would just grab a piece of steel flat bar and use it like a big screwdriver, but I have tons of scrap metal to use. There is a universal tool that most plumbing or big box stores have it will lock onto cross bars or nubs in this case.

Comment: Universal tool: https://www.amazon.com/Superior-Tool-Wrench-Dumbell-Ratchet/dp/B000AO193S (absolutely not an endorsement of that particular one or amazon)

Comment: @EdBeal Good idea -- I just don't have the appropriate scrap metal lying around; most everything I have is sheet metal scraps.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I actually bought one of those to put in the new drain, which has crossbars.  When I tried it on the nubs it barely caught, and I fear that the tool and/or nubs will be damaged if I put any torque into it.

Comment: @calcium3000 there's every chance the nubs will break off, then you'll be back to some of the other methods. (The tool itself is very unlikely to break.) I'd say 'go for it'.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate with a generous amount of penetrating oil the tool you suggested did end up working!  Bits of the handle broke off where the breaker bar contacted it but eventually it gave.  If you provide an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You CAN use Channellock type pliers, just not the way in the linked picture/answer shows. You use the *handles* of the pliers, adjusted to the width of the throat of the tub drain, as spanners. Insert the handles *into the drain* so they are against the nubs, then turn those pliers by putting a pipe wrench, large adjustable wrench, or another set of pliers on the jaws of those pliers (which are pointing up) and turn counter-clockwise.

I have removed numerous tub drains using this method.